# « Jusque demain » : acceptable ou non ?

Tags: usage, prépositions

"Jusqu'aujourd'hui" semble être une alternative acceptable de « jusqu'à aujourd'hui ».

[image]

[Jusqu'aujourd'hui](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jusqu%27aujourd%27hui%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)

« Jusque demain » qui devrait logiquement être aussi acceptable, présente un problème ; c'est comparativement très rare par rapport à « jusqu'à demain », mais il existe quand même un grand nombre d'occurrences et la fréquence a même amorcé une légère croissance ([Jusque demain](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jusque%20demain%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr)).

[image]

Doit-on considérer qu'en raison du grand nombre de cas d'utilisation de cette seconde forme, les deux formes sont aussi acceptables l'une que l'autre (« jusqu'à demain », « jusque demain ») ?

Comment: Jusq'[à-le]-jour-d'hui… telle est donc la raison de l'encéphalogramme plat de ‘jusque demain’… la grammaire vient aussi après l'étymologie ET la philologie…

Comment: @Personne Ce n'est pas analysable grammaticalement, ce qui fait que je n'y ai même pas pensé, et donc la question, pourquoi d'autres s'y seraient attardés, mais ça laisse à réfléchir.

Comment: *Jusqu'hui !* Pourquoi faire simple, quand on peut faire compliqué :-)

Comment: @jlliagre … sauf que *Jusqu'hui !* : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Jusque%27hui&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3… pas très folichon cette belg'attitude https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jusque+demain%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr il manque juste l'accent et le contexte pour comprendre du premier coup

Comment: @Personne Il est vrai que l'usage manifeste au contraire un tropisme irrépressible vers la complexité, je le confesse : ***Jusqu'au jour d'aujourd'hui*** 

Comment: @jlliagre … toto-logiquement lumineux !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Jusqu'aujourd'hui" survit par haplologie, aujourd'hui intégrant déjà la préposition par son étymologie, mais pas dans son usage réel: on dit "d'hier à aujourd'hui" sans le moindre souci (cf "jusqu'au vendredi prochain" pour un exemple régulier de contraction)

La plupart des autres cas où jusque est utilisé sans préposition qui suit sont des adverbes locatifs ou temporels (jusque-là, jusqu'où, jusqu'alors, jusque récemment, "jusque tard dans la nuit" etc)

*Le bon usage* 1065 3˚ relève cependant plusieurs usages de *jusque* avec un groupe nominal plutôt que prépositionnel ("Jusque ce matin" chez Colette, "Jusque la forêt" chez Aragon, "Jusque Halle, [des voitures] rouleront jour et nuit" chez Pierre Gaxotte, "Jusque neuf heures et demie" chez Maxence Van der Meersch) en notant que ces exemples "n'appartient pas à l'usage régulier" mais qu'"un certain nombre paraissent refléter des faits régionaux" qu'il associe à Paris, au Nord, à l'Est de la France et à la Belgique.

Les autres exemples de Goosse et Grevisse sont des adverbes (jusque maintenant, jusqu'hier) ou des quantités (jusque six cent dollars, jusque 38 centièmes de seconde), ce qui me semble quand même un peu différent que les GN cités plus haut.

On retrouve d'ailleurs des attestations dans la presse:

> "la fête du livre de Redu vous donne rendez-vous **jusque ce lundi**" [RTBF](https://www.rtbf.be/article/redu-rassemble-les-amoureux-des-livres-jusqu-a-ce-lundi-7959883) ("jusqu'à ce lundi" dans le titre, par contre)
>
> "Les smartphones envahissent **jusque les églises**" [Sud Ouest](https://www.sudouest.fr/culture/religion/le-pape-se-bat-contre-l-usage-des-telephones-portables-pendant-la-messe-c-est-moche-3260213.php)
>
> "Le Républicain Sud-Gironde remonte le temps **jusque les années 1950**" [Le Républicain](https://actu.fr/nouvelle-aquitaine/langon_33227/avant-apres-l-urbanisation-du-sud-gironde-depuis-les-annees-1950_55971057.html)
>
> "Stromae annule ses concerts **jusque fin mai**" [Le Soir](https://www.lesoir.be/505453/article/2023-04-04/stromae-annule-ses-concerts-jusque-fin-mai)
>
> "**Jusque la journée de ce mercredi soir** plusieurs centaines de maisons sont écroulées" [Radio Okapi](https://www.radiookapi.net/2021/01/14/actualite/societe/haut-lomami-une-femme-tuee-et-plusieurs-maisons-detruites-la-suite-des)
>
> "Enfin Florent Balmont, Dogue **jusque ses 36 ans et 3 mois**, referme le podium" [Le Petit Lillois](https://www.lepetitlillois.com/2022/08/11/jose-fonte-le-doyen-du-losc-en-l1/)

De fait, étant francophone de Belgique, tous ces exemples et le "jusque demain" (ou jusque aujourd'hui, prononcé /ʒyskœoʒɔrdwi/, d'ailleurs) me semblent parfaitement normaux. Mais il parait clair que c'est contraire à une certaine norme, même en Belgique, [comme l'évoque cet éditorial du quotidien belge *Le Soir*](https://www.lesoir.be/art/1370863/article/debats/chroniques/vous-avez-ces-mots/2016-11-18/jusque-lundi-jusqu-lundi).

Deux constats après ces recherches cependant : Bien que j'aie trouvé des exemples dans la presse française, congolaise et belge, ces deux dernières étaient clairement surreprésentées ; et l'absence de préposition semble être bien plus fréquente dans les GN sans déterminant (le type "jusque fin X" en particulier) que dans les GN avec article défini ou indéfini.

À noter finalement que cette absence de préposition n'est possible que lorsque le syntagme nominal reste grammatical sans jusque : pas question de transformer "jusqu'à présent" en "jusque présent", puisque le syntagme de base est "à présent".

Comment: La morale de « l'histoire » serait donc « Ça se trouve mais c'est déconseillé ».